# Location service iOS alert call back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

When we use location services in an application, we receive an iOS alert saying the application is trying to use the current location -- Allow/Don't Allow.

Do we have a delegate call back for these buttons?

I want to handle tap on "Don't Allow".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have direct access to that alert.

If the user presses "Don't Allow", or if the app otherwise doesn't have permission to use location services then `CLLocationManager` will call `locationManager:didFailWithError:` on its delegate.  The error domain will be `kCLErrorDomain` and the error code will be `kCLErrorDenied`.

Comment: This is a good tip, but I find that the alert is displayed before I get this callback, or even the didChangeAuthorizationStatus callback. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @elsurudo, you've probably figured this out by now, but for the record, Apple displays that alert as soon as you start location updates on CLLocationManager. If you want to visually tell the user why you're about to have the system request their location, you'll need to create your own UI for that and avoid starting the location manager until you're sure the user has tapped or swiped on your UI.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply get the action selected like below:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [self addRegion];
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Location access denied");
    }
}
```

make sure to set the delegate of location manager.

Answer (score 3):

You should also check to see if the user has allowed location services for your app before starting the location manager. Use the `CLLocationManager` class method `locationServicesEnabled` to check.

Here's the doc:

> locationServicesEnabled
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.
>
> `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled`
>
> Return Value
>   YES if location services are enabled or NO if they are not.
>
> Discussion
>   The user can enable or disable location services altogether from the Settings application by toggling the switch in Settings > General > Location Services.
>
> You should check the return value of this method before starting location updates to determine if the user has location services enabled for the current device. If this method returns NO and you start location updates anyway, the Core Location framework prompts the user with a confirmation panel asking whether location services should be reenabled.

Comment: This is a bit dangerous as this determines if Location Services are turned ON or OFF, so a user can have Location services turned ON, but OFF for your app specifically.

Comment: It's not dangerous at all, in fact Apple recommends checking for location services being enabled before starting a location manager (look at the sample code for LocateMe in the docs). This is the first thing to check for. You should also check for kCLErrorDenied in the delegate.

Comment: I was a bit vague, sorry. I was meant as a warning to not only rely on the [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] solely as the user could have location services turned on in general, but off for your app:)

Comment: That's true, from the name it looks as if it's doing a complete check for location services, and having to look for kCLErrorDenied later as well isn't all that intuitive.