# iphone location service alert call back allow and don't allow handling

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I have a button in which on click I am authorizing my app to enable location services. I want to capture the allow button event from the alert. As the user press allow, my button color will change to some other color. I am unable to capture the callback of **allow** button. However I am able to capture **don't allow** button event with help of this link

[Location service iOS alert call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905940/location-service-ios-alert-call-back)

Please can anyone tell me how to capture the allow button tap and on success I want to do my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        //allowed - do your logic
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        //denied
    }
}
```

**Swift 4/5**:

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Then handle in delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    case .restricted, .denied:
        // location services unauthorized
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    @unknown default:
        print("New CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() not handled!")
    }    
}
```

Remember to set `locationManager` delegate:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

And implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` by your class.

Comment: @Rajan Is your problem solved? If no, please provide more details, if yes, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: KlimczakM . Thanks. It solved my problem. Sorry was accepting late as I logged stackoverflow after many days. Thanks again